# How to transform the sentence into a question

Tags: grammar

> You point to this pattern I should take to express the idea.

How to transform the above sentence into a question which starts with "which pattern"?

Can I say *"Which pattern did you point to I should take to express the idea"?*
Also, can I substitute **"refer to"** for **"point to"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to.

> Which pattern did you refer to I should take to express the idea

but that sentance still does not make sense, there is a conjunction or ? missing

> Which pattern did you refer to in order for me to express the idea

or

> Which pattern did you refer to so that i may express the idea

i am really just guessing because i am uncertain of you original sentence. 
The word "**pattern**" is not clear to me in the context of expressing an idea